# Best method for robust .NET serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, persistence

I want to save and restore some settings that are currently defined as POCO objects, and want the save/load operations to work even if a change happens in the format of the data being saved so that unknown data is ignored and new data is added correctly.

Which framework can I use? I know I cannot use XML serialization because it's fragile and breaks once it sees an unmatched element in the data structure. What can I use instead that will 'just work'?

Answer (score 4):

While it is XML and it may not handle all changes the DataContractSeralizer can handle adding/removing properties. It also has callbacks to deal with unknown data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx

You can always build your own but that is much more time consuming.

Comment: Not only has it extremely simple hooks to prepare/cleanup data after/before de/serialization and can handle renames, it can even support round-trips through (ex. older) versions of data objects that are missing some elements (ExtensionDataObject).

Comment: Doesn't DCS require `[DataMember]` attributes all over the place? I have hundreds of properties, I need something that can transparently serialize things without any hand-holding.

Comment: Yes it does require [DataMember] to mark all properties that you want serialized. No way around that that i know of for this serializer.
I am not sure if this will help but there is also the SilverlightSerializer. It serializes to binary and can deal with some changes.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `JSON` serialisation, it might do what you need.

However, the best solution is probably to implement your own serialisation to ensure it works in the way that you need it to.  This will ensure that any new values added are handled in exactly the way you need.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "fragile", what you probably mean is "not backwards compatible" or "I changed the contract, and it can't handle my changes".

It's not "fragile" really.  It's more "it doesn't contain artificial intelligence to know what you want when you change something".

Thus, your best bet is to handle it via your own custom serialization mechanism.
Because that is where you will put in the "what if this doesn't exist anymore, but I don't care about that" logic.

There is no "just work" solution, IMHO.  Because one person's "this must exist no matter what the version" is another person's "I can just skip this piece of information in this new version".